# Сортировка данных

Tags: sql-server, сортировка

Такой вопрос
допустим есть к примеру такой запрос:

```
SELECT .... 
   INNER JOIN SELECT ....
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ....
 ORDER BY ....
```

сортировка происходит после всей выборки или перед выборкой?

Comment: что вы хотите отсортировать перед выборкой?

Comment: Нену, логически подумайте,- нафига системе сначала сортировать, потом выбирать?!

Comment: да я понял вопрос стрём нет логики перед выборкой сортировать :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результат выборки отсортирован по ORDER BY ....

Answer (score 1):

Логический порядок обработки инструкции SELECT

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE или WITH ROLLUP (WITH)
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY

Таким образом, сортировка производится на последнем этапе, когда выборка уже завершена.

Подробнее: [SELECT (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)